# Inside a switch statement, is there any way to refer to the value being switched?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, design-patterns, optimization

I have a block of code like

```
switch ( eqtn[curidx] )
{ 
    case Calculator.NOT:
        negateNextOp = true; 
        break;
        // CURMODE remains PARSEMODE.OPER
    case Calculator.OR:
    case Calculator.AND:
    case Calculator.XOR:
        lastop = eqtn[curidx++]; // Set last operator equal to the one at curidx; increment curidx
        CURMODE = PARSEMODE.NUM; // Expecting the next portion of the equation to be a number
        break;
    default: 
         throw new Exception(String.Format("At index {0}, encountered character {1} where expected to encounter beginning of operator",
                                       curidx,
                                       eqtn[curidx])
                             ); // Handle unexpected character 
}
```

and, as you can see, twice inside the `switch` statement I refer to `eqtn[curidx]`, the number being `switch`ed. This seems like it could be made more elegant and optimal. I know that when a `switch` statement is compiled, the value inside the paranthesis something that is "cached" when the code runs and hits the `switch` statement. Since that value is the same as `eqtn[curidx]`, it could result in having two of the same value at different memory addresses (Right?) and that would be useless.

Is there some equivalent of a `this` to refer to the value current being `switch`ed while inside the `switch` block?

Comment: Try this :)
`var x = eqtn[curidx];
switch ( x )`

Comment: "I know that when a switch statement is compiled, the value inside the paranthesis something that is "cached" when the code runs" - I don't know what kind of caching you think is in place... but yes, using a separate local variable is the way to go here.

Comment: I disagree with this being useless. Sure, cloning a large data structure for no reason would be costly and might be useless, but copying an int, a string, or similar, is done all the time, even by the compiler just to have temporary variables during expression evaluation. I would not hesitate at all to write code with the extra variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to refer to "what is being switched on" since the compiler does not in any way create a variable for you that you can access.

Whether the compiler *actually* caches the value or not depends on things that are outside your control.

If you need a cached copy, which may often be a good idea, you will have to make one yourself using a variable:

```
var op = eqtn[curidx];
switch (op)
{
    ...
```

This may be beneficial for several reasons:

1. It makes the code easier to read, you don't need to parse and grok a larger expression to see that it is in fact the same value that is being switched on.
2. It makes the code easier to get correct, you don't risk copy/pasting a bug and fixing it in N-1 places later.
3. The act of evaluating that expression may have a cost, which is now only incurred once.